# Adding a menu component in each option of react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to open a contextual menu when I click a button on the side of each option in rselect options. eact select. I have used a custom option to add button functionality to select optionis. I tried using contextual menu from fluentui but passing the menu immedaiately closes after clicking the button.

Comment: I think adding closeMenuOnSelect: false, would keep the menu open.

Comment: That only works for the dropdown of select not for the contextual Menu added to each option in the dropdown